# InvalidOperationException: Could not get algorithm from X509AsymmetricSecurityKey to make Client Context for SP 2016 in VS 2019

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, authentication, certificate, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to create a context to SP 2016 site with the help of a certificate using following piece of code:

```
OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager othManager = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager();
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 cert = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2({certificate path}, {password to access Certificate});
ClientContext oContext = othManager.GetHighTrustCertificateAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext({siteurl}, {clientID}, cert, {certificate issuer id});
Web objWeb = oContext.Web;
oContext.Load(objWeb);
oContext.ExecuteQuery();
string webTitle = objWeb.Title;
```

However, it is running fine on Visual Studio 2015 but I have various solutions in VS 2019 so it is throwing following exception in VS 2019:

> InvalidOperationException: Could not get algorithm from X509AsymmetricSecurityKey

Even tried following in App.config file of my application but issue persists:

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
</system.web>
```

**Edit:**
Issue still persist after following configuration:

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
</system.web>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

See ["Could not get algorithm from X509AsymmetricSecurityKey" on Framework 4.7 when using S2S #1997](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Sites-Core/issues/1997) for a similar issue. Try adding `<httpRuntimetargetFramework="4.6.2"/>` to `<system.web>`.

Comment: Actually, I tried with 4.6.1. Will try to install .NET Framework 4.6.2 and do the necessary changes in config.

Comment: Issue still persists even for using targetFramework as 4.6.2